# Passing arguments to command pattern

Tags: c++, xml, factory

Okay, normally when I use the command pattern I pass in arguments through the constructor.  However, my current design doesn't really allow that.  The reason being is that I am loading data from an xml file on startup, so I might have something like this:

```
<Actor>
    <InputComponent>
        <Mapping Type="Drag" Key=1 Command="MoveCommand"/>
        <Mapping Type="Press" Key=16 Command="FillerCommand"/>
        <Mapping Type="Click" Key=2 Command="FillerCommand"/>
    </InputComponent>
</Actor>
```

Because they are read in as strings they are passed to a command factory object that then creates the correct command objects and hands em back to the input component.  This means I don't have access to them as they are constructed and thus cannot specify special arguments via constructor.  I could pass this extra info in through a void pointer to the Execute member function but that is terribly insecure.  I could also pass the XML Element to the command factory and have they initialize themselves from further xml attributes (current method) but it still feels like a hack solution.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this at runtime is to uniformly pass parameters when calling, you could use a

`std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any>` or similar as the single argument. Each param would have a name and you will have to cast back `any` to the original type.